# What happen if max pending submits buffer is full in kannel

Tags: sms, kannel

My question is quite simple. I'm working on a project using Kannel to send SMS. In some times it is slow and after hard work i could find it is related to 'max pending submits' buffer. Now i need to confirm it. So I need to know what happen if that buffer is full.

Comment: What is your kannel version?

Comment: @SaveendraEkanayake 1.4.1